# Building CUDA code using modern CMake: how to build with a different CUDA toolkit

Tags: cmake, cuda

Before the advent of modern CMake CUDA was treated as a third party library, which made it convenient when "cross-compiling". One just needed the library and headers of the cuda toolkit installed in the target machine. Now my understanding is that this is not so easy to do anymore, because the `enable_language(CUDA)` command will make additional checks (which is great) and it will fail if one has different drivers than the ones used for building. Is that correct? Is there an easy way to do such cross-compilation in modern CMake, or one has to resort to the obsolete FindCUDA.cmake?

Comment: I just saw that there is some recent development in CMake to support the usage of a CUDA toolkit from an arbitrary location, https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/3713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from CMake version >= 16.4 one can coose an arbitrary folder (which we will call `<path-to-folder>`) and put the CUDA toolkit (which is usually in e.g. `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2`) in `<path-to-folder>/nvcc`, together with the Visual Studio integration files (which you can usually find in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\extras\visual_studio_integration`) in `<path-to-folder>/CUDAVisualStudioIntegration/extras/visual_studio_integration` and then set in CMake the variable `-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET=cuda=<path-to-folder>`